# Repository Pattern Contestation

Tags: linq, design-patterns, orm, repository

According to [Martin Fowler](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/repository.html):

> ... "Client objects construct query
>   specifications declaratively and
>   submit them to Repository for
>   satisfaction" ...

Why? What are the advantages at that point?

I see one disadvantage: database queries are spread and hidden over ties. That makes it harder to debug.

Answer (score 2):

The advantage is that the "what" (the declarative specification) is separated from the "how" or implemenation details.  So the client doesn't need to know whether it's querying a relational database, a Web service, an object database (eg Mongo), an XML data store, etc.

Let's assume you're using an RDBMS.  Even so, the client is isolated from needing to know whether the database is Oracle, MS SQL, SQLite, mySQL, PostGres, etc.  This will save you a lot of headache when the commandment "thou shalt (not) use MS SQL" (or whatever) comes down from the mountain.

The additional layer does introduce some overhead.  But (1) ORM tools like (N)Hibernate are quite good at optimizing the generated queries for whatever back-end you're using, and (2) the overhead is generally negligible compared to the cost of database read, let alone a web service call.

We're converting from LINQ to NHibernate right now to avoid the "N+1" problem (ie you generate one query/hit for each "master" database record, plus a query/hit for each "child" record).
And BTW ... there is such a thing as LINQ to NHibernate.